# Find feature or combination of features that has an effect

Tags: statistics

I am looking for a statistical model or test to answer following question and would be grateful for some help:

I have m products p1,...,p5 that my customers can subscribe to.
I have divided my customers into groups A1,...,A and for each group and each combination of products, I have counted how many customers have this combination of products, and how it has affected their sales:

`Customer_group  has_p1  has_p2 [...]  has_p5  cust_count  total_sales
A1              0       0             0       124         1234
A1              1       0             0       315         999
A1              1       1             0       199         7777
[...]
An              1       1             1       233         663`

Now I want to find out which group of customers benefit from which product or combination of products.

My first idea was to use a **paired t test** for the group of customers that had a product versus the group that does not have a product in the same combination with other products, i.e. for measuring the effect of p1 I would pair {A1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0} with {A1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0} and compare the series of the two values of total_sales/cust_count.

However, with this test I just find out which of the products has an effect, not which group it has an effect for or if it is significant that the product is sold in combination with another product.

Any good ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So after thinking a day, I found a way:

First I did a one-hot encoding of the groups, so I replaced the customer_group column with n columns containing 0 and 1's.

Then I made a linear regression model with mixed terms:

product_i * product_j + group_k * product_i + group_k * product_i * product_j

And by reducing the model I found which product x product combinations and which group x product and group x product x product combinations were significant